# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool Ubuntu applications
- the site's Twitter account
- Ubuntu scripts or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/16682).

Answer (score 16):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Comment: `Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: ask` =/

Comment: @anatolytechtonik We'll look in to adding the command if the site graduates. :D

Comment: Once you click that banner, you won't be able to exit it. :P

Answer (score 14):

[image: NitroShare - cross-platform file transfer application]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Why zsh is cooler than your shell]

Answer (score 11):

[image: RecuperaBit – Open Source NTFS Recovery]

Answer (score 9):

[image: George Edison - penguin on a mission]

Comment: +1 just for the cute penguin.

Answer (score 9):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Comment: Copied from last year.

Comment: I like this, but if I understand the rules correctly its border should be 2px because it's HiDPI.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: Not sure; I believe the project's source is [here](https://github.com/kylecronin/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad). Open an issue there.

Comment: Well actually I saw another problem now. It says “Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)” in the rules.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: As you can see, this is not enforced.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: No.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Join your fellow community members in chat!]

Comment: We had this advert that I made live last year.

Answer (score 8):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Hectane - lightweight MTA]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Internet of Things Beta]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Ask Ubuntu General Room Twitter feed]

Comment: Too much text, I think

Comment: @Seth: How about "Ask Ubuntu has a chat room. We also have a Twitter account. Check it out, you should?". Is that better?

Comment: What if you just used a funny quote from the twitter account?

Comment: @Seth: of these three, which do you like best? https://twitter.com/ChattyCapybaras/status/817855230222147585 , https://twitter.com/ChattyCapybaras/status/816768066642124804 , or https://twitter.com/ChattyCapybaras/status/812419412225589249 ?

Comment: probably the first one

Comment: I vote for the second since I really think tha. . . oh, look banana!

Comment: -1 too much bacon

Answer (score 4):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Comment: This probably could have been reduced to 2 lines via `if like(computer science) and (like(learning) or like(teaching)):` ;)

Comment: Seconding that^. Also I'd probably write: `if you.like(computer.science) ...` and so on.

Comment: Indeed, that space between computer and science would be a syntax error. Or you could turn those into quoted strings. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Comment: I would vote for this if it was retina sized - could you update the template?

Answer (score 1):

[image: REVIEW!]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Follow your fellow AU members in chat!]

Comment: Don't we already have one of these? https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16708/158442

Comment: @muru well we had 2 last year and since the site makes chat hard to find I figured we could have 2 again.

Comment: You should probably publicise this ad on chat, perhaps.